# How to change image color in openlayers3?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas, openlayers-3

I am new to openlayers3. I am showing point as a image but I want to change color of image dynamically.Is it possible in openlayers3 or have any other facility like canvas in openlayers3?

```
var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({ 
    image: new ol.style.Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
         anchor: [0.5, 46], 
         anchorXUnits: 'fraction', 
         anchorYUnits: 'pixels', 
         src: 'data/icon.png' 
    })) 
});
```

Comment: You'll need another image to replace the original, but yes, it is possible. You should share the code you're using to get more specific help.

Comment: I don't want to replace original image with another image which has different color. I want to use same image with different color

Comment: var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
          anchor: [0.5, 46],
          anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
          anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
          src: 'data/icon.png'
        }))
      });

Comment: As far as I know you can't change the color of a PNG in a `ol.style.Icon` object. If we were talking about an `img` tag, you could use [CSS3 Filters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/filter?v=example) to achieve something like that; but I guess there's no way to do this inside a `ol` object.

Answer (score 0):

Taking [Icon Colors](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/icon-color.html) as starting point where they use a transparent PNG with `ol.Color` option to have multiple color dots I've tried to change the colors like this without success...

```js
var london = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([-0.12755, 51.507222]))
});


london.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
  image: new ol.style.Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
    color: '#ff0000',
    crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
    src: 'https://openlayers.org/en/v4.1.1/examples/data/dot.png'
  }))
}));


var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: [london]
});

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource
});

var rasterLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.TileJSON({
    url: 'https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/mapbox.geography-class.json?secure',
    crossOrigin: ''
  })
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [rasterLayer, vectorLayer],
  target: document.getElementById('map'),
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([2.896372, 44.60240]),
    zoom: 3
  })
});

map.on('singleclick', function (event) { // Use 'pointermove' to capture mouse movement over the feature 
  map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(event.pixel, function (feature, layer) {
    /* Get the current image instance and its color */
    var image = feature.getStyle().getImage();
    console.log(image.getColor());
    
    /* Color gets stored in image.i, but there's no setter */
    console.log(image.i);
    
    /* Trying to force the color change: */
    image.i = [0, 255, 0, 1];
    
    /* Dispatch the changed() event on layer, to force styles reload */
    layer.changed();
    
    console.log(image.getColor()); // Logs new color, but it doesn't work...
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
<script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.1.1/build/ol.js"></script>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

See how you can retrieve an icon's color like this:

```
var image = feature.getStyle().getImage(),
    color = image.getColor(); // returns [R, G, B, alpha]
```

but there's no `setColor()` method, so there's no way to change the color in runtime...

---

**EDIT:** Reviewing again your question and your code, I've noticed you never set a color for your icon, so maybe you don't really want to actually *change* the color in response to an event but just *set* a color. If that's what you want, then it's easy:

```
var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({ 
     image: new ol.style.Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
         anchor: [0.5, 46], 
         anchorXUnits: 'fraction', 
         anchorYUnits: 'pixels', 
         src: 'data/icon.png',
         color: '#ff0000' // allows HEX as String or RGB(a) as Array
     })) 
});
```

See: http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.style.Icon.html